# Given a directed graph and two vertices ‘u’ and ‘v’ in it, count all the possible walks from ‘u’ to ‘v’ with exactly k edges on the walk

Tags: c++, graph, dynamic-programming

My code is failing for the following test case , please help

```
1
10
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
2 7 3

Its Correct output is:
11

And Your Code's output is:
6
```

Given a directed graph and two vertices ‘u’ and ‘v’ in it, count all the possible walks from ‘u’ to ‘v’ with exactly k edges on the walk.

Input:

The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case consists of three lines.
The first line of each test case is N which is number of vertices in input graph.
The second line of each test case contains N x N binary values that represent graph[N][N].
The third line of each test case contains u, v, k where u is starting position, v is destination and k is number of edges.

```
Output:

Print all possible walks from 'u' to 'v'.

Constraints:

1 ≤ T ≤ 50
1 ≤ N ≤ 20
0 ≤ graph[][] ≤ 1

Example:

Input
1
4
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 3 2

Output
2
```

Explanation:

For example consider the following graph. Let source ‘u’ be vertex 0, destination ‘v’ be 3 and k be 2. The output should be 2 as there are two walk from 0 to 3 with exactly 2 edges. The walks are {0, 2, 3} and {0, 1, 3}

**MY CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //code
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int r,c;
        cin>>r;
        c=r;
        int arr[r][c];
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
            {
                cin>>arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        int u,v,k;
        cin>>u>>v>>k;
        int dp[r][k+1];
        for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<k+1;j++)
            {
                dp[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        dp[u][0]=1;

        for(int j=0;j<k+1;j++)
            {
               for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
              {
                if(dp[i][j]!=0)
                {
                    for(int x=0;x<r;x++)
                    {
                        if(arr[i][x]==1)
                        {if(j+1<k+1)
                            dp[x][j+1]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
               }
            }
            cout<<dp[v][k]<<endl;
        
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seem like a problem that would be much easier to solve using recursive algorithm.
I'll be honest, this code is really hard to read for a lot of reson, for example there isno meaningful variable names (e.g `arr` should probably be `AdjMat`)
I would also recommend to edit the question so the input (binary string) will be in the form of adjacency matrix representation

Comment: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-number-of-paths-of-length-k-in-a-directed-graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-number-of-paths-of-length-k-in-a-directed-graph) ?